# How to read the below json using php

Tags: php, json

I'm able to decode a json in php and below is the output using `print_r($data)`.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sys_msg] => stdClass Object
        (
            [old_expiry_date] => 2015-06-25 00:00:00+00:00
            [new_expiry_date] => 2015-12-25 00:00:00+05:30
            [phone] => +919990321320
            [userplan_id] => 65960
        )

    [user_msg] => SMEDELIVRY-38793
)
```

Now how do I parse this to get the details?

```
foreach($data as $data) {
echo "Expiry:".$data->old_expiry_date;echo "<br />";
```

Outputs the correct date but I'm not able to parse the `[user_msg]` bit. I get an error:

> Expiry:2015-06-25 00:00:00+00:00
>
> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sr/log.php on line 39
>
> Expiry:

Comment: Can you post the raw json, it would help to reproduce the code.

Comment: `foreach($data as $data)` is redefining `$data`. Change it to something like `foreach($data as $msg)`.

Answer (score 3):

`$data` is not an array, it's an object, there's nothing to loop over.

```
echo "Expiry: " . $data->sys_msg->old_expiry_date . "<br/>";
```

Your error is because the `user_msg` property is a string, not an object, so it doesn't have an `old_expiry_date` property. To show that, use:

```
echo "Message: " . $data->user_msg . "<br/>";
```

Comment: to add to this, $data->user_msg would return the string.